# Reading a C string line by line

Tags: c

I am trying to parse SIP headers into a line. I do this by iterating over a string line by line. Each header should be separated by a new line character.

The input string will look something similar to this:

```
INVITE sip:user2@server2.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP pc33.server1.com;branch=z9hG4bK776asdhds Max-Forwards: 70 
To: user2 <sip:user2@server2.com>
From: user1 <sip:user1@server1.com>;tag=1928301774
Call-ID: a84b4c76e66710@pc33.server1.com 
CSeq: 314159 INVITE 
Contact: <sip:user1@pc33.server1.com>
Content-Type: application/sdp 
Content-Length: 142
```

My code:

```
void readlines(char *str){
  int i;
  int reset;
  char current_line[500];
  char tmp = 0;
  for( i=0; i<strlen(str); i++ ){
      tmp = str[i];
    if (tmp == '\n'){
      strncpy(current_line, str+tmp, i);
      strcat(current_line, '\0');
      printf("current line = %s", current_line);
    }
  }
}
```

In my code you can see an if block. In the if block I print out the current line as a cheap way to test my solution, the result of this print statement is nothing. Maybe my understanding on how c interprets the `\n` character is not complete.

Comment: take a look at the `strtok` function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I've already looked into this function. From my understanding it is not thread safe, which is a requirement for me.

Comment: One issue I found and did not realize, is I was testing this function by passing a command line argument with a \n. But the way I was passing the testing string took the \n literally and not as a new line character

Comment: You cannot use `strcat` to append null termination, because it requires string to be null terminated before use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031075/strtok-function-thread-safety... this page suggests using strtok_r for thread safety

Comment: Also, *"this does not work"*  is not valid problem description. **Always** provide input, and both expected and actual output, along with any possible error messages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299987/loop-through-char-array-line-by-line

Comment: I updated the question to better reflect and show what I am looking for. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The code has type errors, tmp is char variable so str+tmp pointer arithmetic is meaningless.  Similarly, '\0' is a char, NOT a char * NULL terminated string that can be appended by strcat.  To NULL terminate assign '\0' to the end of the data copied.  So copy length terminated by '\n', then append '\0'!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983005/c-how-to-read-a-string-line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983005/c-how-to-read-a-string-line-by-line)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, `strtok_r` is the ideal function for this.  It is used to parse a string based on delimiters, and takes a separate pointer for state so that it's safe in multithreaded programs.

```
void readlines(char *str){
  char *p, *temp;
  p = strtok_r(str, "\n", &temp);
  do {
      printf("current line = %s", p);
  } while ((p = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &temp)) != NULL);
}
```

Note that this function modifies the string it is working on, so make a copy and work on that if need be.

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments, `strtok_r` is only available on POSIX systems, i.e. not Windows.  For Windows, the equivalent function is `strtok_s`.

Comment: Note: `strtok_r` is POSIX only.

Comment: @user694733  Thanks.  Edited to give an alternative to Windows.

Comment: FWIW: There is the `strtok_s()` in C11 Appendix K with similar multithreaded functionality.

Comment: Do you mean `while ((p = strtok_r(NULL, "\n", &temp)) != NULL)`? Note: `=` instead of `-` and add extra `)` before `!=`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Correct.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on POSIX, use its [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) function (probably on a `FILE*` which is your TCP socket, eg. using `fdopen`; or you could get a `FILE*` handle from a buffer using `fmemopen`). If you don't have `getline`, standard C99 has `fgets` but you'll either limit the line length to some fixed size buffer length or need to reallocate it.

If you have already all the header data in some buffer, you can parse it using `sscanf` (handle its return count, use also `%n`), or parse it manually (e.g. using some `strcmp`), etc. And of course `strtok_r` as mentioned by others.

Did you consider using some existing [SIP implementation](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/sip/implementations.html) library?
Notably GNU [oSIP](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/)?

Answer (score 0):

the posted code contains a few problems.

missing the header files:

```
#include <stdio.h> // printf()
#include <string.h> // strlen(), strncpy(), strcat()
```

the `strcat()` expects both parameters to be `char*` not an actual character
So the call to strcat() should be:

```
strcat(current_line, "\0");
```

Now, regarding the execution of the code.

(assume `str` is a pointer to an array of char that is not NUL terminated and is less than 500 bytes long)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readlines(char *str)
{
    size_t i;
    char *current_line = NULL;

    for( i = 0; i< 500 && '\n' != str[i]; i++);

    if( NULL == (current_line = calloc( i+2, 1 ) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "calloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    memcpy( current_line, str, i );
    printf("current line = %s", current_line);
    free( current_line );
}
```