# How do I store a line in a dynamic double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Im working on a project and I need to know how to store a line read from a file into a dynamic double pointer. For example assume I have this struct:

```
typedef struct { 
char **data; /*dynamic array of lines */
size_t nused; /*number of lines in the dynamic array */
} lines_t;
```

and in my readline function:

```
lines_t readline() { 
    lines_t line_data;
    char line[LINESIZE]; 
    char *data; 
    line_data.data = malloc(sizeof(char *)*sizeof(line));
    line_data.nused = 1;
    while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) {
       data = line; 
       line_data.data = &data;  
       nalloc++;  
    } 
    printf("%s",*line_data.data); 
    return line_data; 
}
```

But this will always print the very last line in the file, How can I make it so that I can access and print any line in the file?(I think I may have to index the double pointer)

Comment: Where do you allocate the new list holder (holding array), and where do you copy your old list holder's contents to the new list holder, and then add in the new line?

Comment: `data = line` needs to be replaced by allocating memory and copying from `line` into it. get rid of `char *data`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lines_t readline() { 

    lines_t line_data;
    char line[LINESIZE]; 
    char *data; 

    // Allocates enough space for the array, but not the text
    line_data.data = malloc(sizeof(char *)* LINESIZE);

    // Zero indexed
    line_data.nused = 0;

    while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) {

       // Allocates space for each line
       line_data.data[line_data.nused] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(line) + 1));

       // Copies the string from the buffer
       strcpy(line_data.data[line_data.nused], line);

       // One more line processed
       line_data.nused++;

       // I'm not sure what this is or what it's for
       //nalloc++;
    } 
    printf("%s",*line_data.data); 
    return line_data; 
}
```

BTW, to answer the actual question. You can print all lines like this:

```
for (int it=0 ; it < line_data.nused ; ++it) {
    printf("%s", line_data.data[it]);
}
```

Comment: You might want to strip `\n` from the fgets result

Comment: I'm not sure I should. There was no attempt in the initial post

Answer (score 3):

If your system has it, use the POSIX [getline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html). You'll probably need to duplicate the gotten line using [strdup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html), at least if you call `getline` in a loop with the same arguments.

Notice that [André Fratelli's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31527174/841108) is limiting the line size to `LINESIZE` but `getline` don't have such limitation (and could read wide lines of many thousand characters). Of course it will fail if the used `malloc` is failing.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5597513/841108) related question.

On GNU systems like Linux you might want to use the [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library, if reading from the terminal. It adds editing abilities (and enables auto-completion).

<sup>Hence your `readline` name is slightly confusing. You might add a comment telling that it is not the GNU readline library, or change the name to something else, like `read_a_line` ....</sup>

BTW, you'll better grow & allocate your vector only once in a while, using some `newsize = 3*oldsize/2 + 50;` nearly [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). Then you need to keep both allocated and used sizes:

```
typedef struct { 
   char **data; /*dynamic array of nallocated lines */
   size_t nallocated; // allocated size of `data` above
   size_t nused; // count of used lines in the dynamic array
   /// invariant: nused <= nallocated
} lines_t;
```

At last, don't forget to test `malloc` (& `calloc` & `realloc`) and `fgets` or `getline` or `readline` against failure. On Linux, use `ulimit` in the shell, which calls [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (you want `RLIMIT_AS`), to stress test against `malloc` failure.

Comment: This answer is better than mine. You should take it.